# php 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php

I had this problem when i've re installed my php script on my server but then it comes this error like in the picture but then after doing a search and i found it is a .htaccess error or something like that please if anyone can help it would be nice thanksss.

check picture of error:
enter image description here
[image]

```
    ############################################
# SERVER WISE SETTINGS
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini

##  cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
##  RewriteBase /
##  AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php


############################################
# CUSTOM SEO FRIENDLY URL REWRITING
############################################


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

############################################
## The code below should help against Local and Remote File Inclusion attacks.


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(http|https|ftp):\/\/(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*=(ht|f)tp\://.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

############################################
## use URL encoding in the http:// part

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http%3A%2F%2F [OR]


############################################
## Adding the following directive should give you an additional layer of security 
## against this type of attacks using the proc/self/environ method.

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc\/self\/environ [NC,OR] 


###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    #php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off


############################################
# PASS THE DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
############################################

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

############################################
# DISABLE THE SERVER SIGNATURE
############################################

ServerSignature Off

############################################
# SECURE HTACCESS FILE
############################################

<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

################################
# UPDATING TEMPLATES, JAVASCRIPT OR CSS FILE WITHOUT HITTING MOD_SECURITY.
# THIS SETTING MOSTLY HANDY WHEN YOU ARE MODIFYING TEMPLATES FROM ADMIN AREA.
################################

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

################################
# Disable directory browsing
################################

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
IndexIgnore *

################################
# PROTECT .htaccess and .htpasswd FILES
################################

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy all
</FilesMatch>

################################
# PREVENT FILE VIEWING WITH HTACCESS
################################

<Files ~ "\.(pl|jsp|cgi|py|sh|cgi|exe|dll|lo|shtml|phtml)$">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</Files>

################################
# PPROTECT CONFIG.* FILES
################################

<FilesMatch "^(.*)\.(inc|txt|dat|shtml|exe|dll|pl|cgi|jsp|asp|aspx|ini|sh|zip)$">
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


############################################
# DISABLING EXECUTING OF FOLLOWING FILES.
############################################

AddHandler cgi-script .pl .py .jsp .asp .jsp  .shtml .sh .cgi .pl .aspx .zip .phtml
Options -ExecCGI

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>


############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `Deny from all` with `Allow from all` except `<FilesMatch "^\.ht">`

Comment: Did you check file permissions?